# SPSS two way repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: spss, anova, two-way

i am fairly new with statitistic.
I made an experiment and used the two way ANOVA with repeated measures. The calculation was done in SPSS. In most papers I have seen, the f-value and the degree of freedom were reported as well. is it normal to report those values as well? if so, which values do i take from the spss output.
how do I interpret these values? what do they mean? 
when does the f-value support a significant result and when not?
what are good values for the f-value and the degree of freedom. 
in some article is also read about the critical f-values, how do I get this value?
most articles describe how to calculate those values but do not explain their meaning for the experiment.
some clarification in these issues is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My English is not very good, but I will try to answer your question.

The main purpose of ANOVA is that we want statistical proof that the measured groups have the same mean or not. So we make a null hypothesis and an alternative hypothesis, then we use a test statistics on the data. You can use ANOVA if the groups has the same variance (squared standard deviation).

You need to test this. This is a hyptest too, the nullhyp. is the groups have the same variance, the anternative hyp. is they dont.

You need to make decision from the Sig. value, if the value is higher than 0,05, we usually accept the nullhyp. If the variances are equal, we can use ANOVA. (I assume that the data is following the Normal distribution.) The nullhyp. is that the groups have equal means, the alternative hyp is that we have at least 1 group with a different mean. You can make your decision from the Sig. value, as I said before, if the value higher than 0.05 we accept the nullhyp. The F-critical value is not important if you are calculating on a computer. You can make an accepting interval from the lower and the upper F-critical, and if the F-value is in the interval you accept the nullhyp, but I only used this method in statistics class. You don't need the F-value and the df in the report, because they don't explain anything on their own.